# Управление системой Windows в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

Необходимо изменять настройки/параметры системы Windows 10 через python, к примеру:

- Выключение звука
- Выключение ПК
- Выключение интернета
- Уменьшение яркости
- И т. п.

Какой самый хороший вариант реализации будет?
(Да, все можно сделать через консоль с помощью os.system, но я думаю что это не совсем верное решение)

Comment: Гуглить соответствующие части Win32 API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

пример перезапуска службы Диспетчер печати с помощью [pywinrm](https://github.com/diyan/pywinrm)

```
import winrm

def spooler_restart(server):
    ad_user, ad_pass = get_ad_data()
    s = winrm.Session(server, auth=(ad_user, ad_pass), transport='ntlm')  # server = IP or DNS
    stop = s.run_cmd('net stop spooler')
    status_stop = stop.std_out.translate(None, b'\r\n').decode('cp866').replace('The ', '').replace('.', '\n')
    time.sleep(1)
    start = s.run_cmd('net start spooler')
    status_start = start.std_out.translate(None, b'\r\n').decode('cp866').replace('The ', '').replace('.', '\n')

    if 'stopped successfully' in status_stop and 'started successfully' in status_start:
        return str(stop.status_code) + ', Служба успешно остановлена\n' + \
               str(start.status_code) + ', Служба успешно запущена'
    else:
        return str(stop.status_code) + str(start.status_code)
```